# How do I set a resource name for an app in Azure AD

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Using OAuth2 I have an auth url similar to:
https://login.windows.net/{TENENT_ID}/oauth2/authorize?resource={APPLICATION_ID}

And this all works fine. However ideally I'd like to assign the application with a name so APPLICATION_ID can be replaced with something more readable.

I've tried using the App name but this gets rejected.

Is there any way to do this in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, we use the **App ID URI** as the resource parameter instead of the application ID. And you can add your application name with your domain to identify the resource. For example, `http://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/Office365REST` is one of my app id URI.

More detail about URI, you can refer [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

Comment: How do I find out what my App ID URI is in the Azure interface? I can't see that anywhere

Comment: We will register the web app for protecting the resource. And you can find the **App ID URI** in the single sign-on section on the [Azure old portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).

Comment: Ah, I was using the new portal so I missed this

Answer (score 1):

No. The `resource` parameter can only be the encoded resource URI of the application.